# How to use react addons with React.NET

Tags: .net, reactjs, add-on

I am trying to use the react addon component, ReactCSSTransitionGroup, within a project that is using server-side rendering and React.NET.

Whenever I call @Html.React() within a view to start the server-side rendering, I get the following exception.

> Error while rendering "WorkOrderGeneralTab" to "react1": Script threw
>   an exception: 'ReactCSSTransitionGroup' is undefined. Line: 0 Column:0

How can I get the react.net server-side renderer to recognise the definition of react addons like the CSSTransitionGroup?

Here is what I am doing elsewhere that is likely relevant

- react-with-addons.js (v0.13.1) is being bundled and sent to the client, along with our own jsx files.

Here is whats in my ReactConfig.cs

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
            .AddScript("~/Scripts/react-with-addons.js")
            .AddScript("~/Features/WorkOrder/_Notes.jsx")
            .AddScript("~/Features/WorkOrder/_General.jsx");
```

Here is the server-side code (within a .cshtml file) that is throwing the exception

```
@Html.React("WorkOrderGeneralTab", new
{
    workOrder = Model,
    tabName = "General",
    softCloseUrl = @Url.Action("SoftClose"),
    reopenUrl = @Url.Action("Reopen"),
    userPermissions = new { 
        softClose = @Html.UserHas(Permission.WorkOrderSoftClose),
        reopen = @Html.UserHas(Permission.WorkOrderReopen)
    }
})
```

Finally, here is the component that is throwing the exception. This component is instantiated and rendered by the WorkOrderGeneralTab's render function.

```
var WOGeneralActionButtons = React.createClass({displayName: 'WOGeneralActionButtons',
  render: function() {
    var closeOrReopenBtn;
    // logic that chooses close vs reopen button... 

    var CopyDeleteButtons = <WOCopyDeleteButtons/>;
    var ExportPrintButtons = <WOExportPrintButtons/>;
    return (
          <div className="col-md-6 text-right">
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
              {closeOrReopenBtn}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            {CopyDeleteButtons}
            {ExportPrintButtons}
          </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I also have some css defined to back the transitionName="example".

What am I missing to get the server-side renderer to recognise ReactCSSTransitionGroup as a valid component? If I remove the ReactCSSTransitionGroup tag, everything else works as-is (hold the transition animation).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted all code, this might be incorrect. But `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is not a global variable, it's located on the `React.addons` object. So you need this:

`var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;`

Somewhere in your code before you use it.

Comment: Sure enough, that simple change got rid of the error I was hitting. Thanks a bunch!